# How to center image in a button using TableLayout

Tags: android, button

I am trying to center the image (plus sign) within a button, that also has a text below. But I cannot figure out how to solve this.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="add measure"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Any help is welcome, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Button Place Image in center and text at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277382/android-button-place-image-in-center-and-text-at-bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I would suggest you to implement a Frame layout since you want to display an image on the button along with text info. Within the frame layout, include your ImageView (your plus sign in this case) and a textview (the title of your button or what ever you wish to call it).

XML File

```
<TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ADD MEASURE"
                        android:layout_below="@id/image"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
            </FrameLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

You must also include the following statements in your main activity because the elements will always remain hidden behind your button. Therefore, you will need to wire in your Layout and use the same function as mine in the MainActivity.

MainActivity class

```
RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.bringToFront();
```

Please do note that I did not have an image of the plus sign so I used an image which was already in the drawable folder.
[image: The Output]

Let me know if this worked or if I competently off the grid according to your question ;)